# Printf output of pointer string explanation from an interview

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I had an interview and I was given this code and asked what is the output for each one of these printf statements.

I have my answers as comments, but I am not sure about the rest.

Can anyone explain the different outputs for statements 1, 3 and 7 and why?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *s = "12345";

    printf("%d\n", s);      // 1.Outputs "3999" is this the address of the first pointer?
    printf("%d\n", *s);     // 2.The decimal value of the first character
    printf("%c\n", s);      // 3.Outputs "\237" What is this value?
    printf("%c\n", *s);     // 4.Outputs "1"
    printf("%c\n", *(s+1)); // 5.Outputs "2"
    printf("%s\n", s);      // 6.Outputs "12345"
    printf("%s\n", *s);     // 7.I get an error, why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to point out - this interview is a sad joke. The company that you interviewed at is hiring compilers, not SW engineers.

Comment: This was one of the basic questions to see if I understsnd the basics of printf and different types and calls.

Comment: I would recommend you try another working place buddy. I'd be happy to explain why in detail off SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following [online C compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) in order to run your code,
and here are the results:

```
1. 4195988            - undefined behaviour (UB), manifesting here as the address
                        of the char array as you stated (for a 64 bit address you might or
                        might not get truncation)
2. 49                 - ASCII value of '1'
3. �                  - undefined behaviour, manifesting here as unsupported ASCII value
                        for a truncation of the address of the array of chars
                        (placing 32-bit address into a char - assuming a 32-bit system)
4. 1                  - obvious
5. 2                  - obvious
6. 12345              - obvious
7. Segmentation fault - undefined behaviour, trying to place the first char
                        of a char array into a string reserved position
                        (placing char into a string)
```

Note on point number 3: we can deduce what took place during run-time.
In the specific example provided in the question -

```
printf("%c\n", s);      // 3.Outputs "\237". What is this value?
```

This is a hardware/compiler/OS related behavior when handling the UB.

Why? Due to the output "\237" -> this implies truncation *under the specific hardware system executing this code*!

Please see the explanation below (assumption - 32-bit system):

```
char *s = "12345"; // Declaring a char pointer pointing to a char array
char c = s; // Placement of the pointer into a char - our UB
printf("Pointer to character array: %08x\n", s); // Get the raw bytes
printf("Pointer to character: %08x\n", c); // Get the raw bytes
printf("%c\n", s); // place the pointer as a character
                   // display is dependent on the ASCII value and the OS
                   // definitions for 128-255 ASCII values
```

The outputs:

```
Pointer to character array: 004006e4  // Classic 32-bit pointer
Pointer to character: ffffffe4        // Truncation to a signed char
                                      // (Note signed MSB padding to 32 bit display)
�                                     // ASCII value E4 = 228 is not displayed properly
```

The final printf command is equivalent to `char c = s; printf("%c\n", c);`.
Why? Thanks to truncation.

An additional example with a legitimate ASCII character output:

```
    char *fixedPointer = 0xABCD61; // Declaring a char pointer pointing to a dummy address
    char c = fixedPointer; // Placement of the pointer into a char - our UB
    printf("Pointer to 32-bit address: %08x\n", fixedPointer); // Get the raw bytes
    printf("Pointer to character: %08x\n", c); // Get the raw bytes
    printf("%c\n", fixedPointer);
```

And the actual outputs:

```
Pointer to 32-bit address: 00abcd61
Pointer to character: 00000061
a
```

Comment: Even assuming "32-bit system", code such as `char *s = "12345"; printf("Pointer to character array: %08x\n", s);` remains _undefined behavior_ and not a reliable legitimate ASCII character output.  Such code lacks future correctness & maintainability even if it initial "works" as desired.  It should be clearly identified as UB - especially in an interview Q&A.  IOWs, detailed explanation of how the UB could occur takes away from the emphasis, during the interview, the importance that the code is fundamentally deficient.

Comment: @chux : The core principle is simple - do not code UB. Never code anything that derives from UB. I've seen horrible bugs/side effects caused by UB and always tried to fight it.
Period. New Line. During a job interview, if asked on a certain behavior, after making it absolutely clear that it is, indeed, UB - one can show a deeper understanding by explaining what the UB has caused.

Answer (score 5):

This call

```
printf("%d\n", s);
```

has undefined behavior because an invalid format specifier is used with a pointer.

This call

```
printf("%d\n", *s);
```

outputs the internal code (for example ASCII code) of the character `'1'`.

This call

```
printf("%c\n", s);
```

has undefined behavior due to using an invalid format specifier with a pointer.

These calls

```
printf("%c\n", *s);
printf("%c\n", *(s+1));
```

are valid. The first one outputs the character `'1'` and the second one outputs the character `'2'`.

This call

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

is correct and outputs the string `"12345"`.

This call

```
printf("%s\n", *s);
```

is invalid because an invalid format specifier is used with an object of the type `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The 7'th line is failing because a C style string is expected as an input, and you are placing a character instead.

Take a look at:

- [What does %s and %d mean in printf in the C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026980/what-does-s-and-d-mean-in-printf-in-the-c-language)
- [C style strings guide](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

1. This code is undefined behaviour (UB). You are passing a pointer, where the function requires an `int` value. For example, in a 64-bit architecture, a pointer is 64 bit, and an `int` is 32 bit.  You can be printing a truncated value.
2. You are passing the first `char` value (automatically converted to an `int` by the compiler) and print it in decimal. Probably you got `49` (the ASCII code for `'1'`. This is legal use, but be careful about surprises, as you can get negative values if your platform `char` implementation is `signed`.
3. You are printing the passed pointer reinterpreted as a `char` value.  Undefined behaviour, as you cannot convert a pointer to a `char` value.
4. You are printing the pointed value of `s` as a `char` so you get the first character of string `"12345"` (`'1'`).
5. You are printing the next to first `char` pointed to by `s`, so you get the second character of string (`'2'`).
6. You are printing the string pointed to by `s`, so you get the whole string. This is legal and indeed, the common way to print a string.
7. You are passing the first character of string to be interpreted as a pointer to a null terminated string to be printed (which it isn't). This is undefined behaviour again. You are reinterpreting a `char` value as a pointer to a null terminated string. A `SIGSEGV` is common in this case, (but not warranted :) )  The signal is sent when the program tries to access unallocated memory before reaching the supposed null character that terminates the string (but it could find a `'\0'` in the way and just print rubbish).