# why result of (double + int) is 0 (C language)

Tags: c, int, double

result of

`printf("%d\n", 5.0 + 2);`

is 0

but

```
int num = 5.0 + 2;
printf("%d\n", num);
```

is 7

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Refer to this answer it will help more https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027033/7865621

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of `5.0 + 2` is `7.0` and is of type `double`.

The `"%d"` format is to print `int`.

Mismatching format specification and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

To print a `float` or `double` value with [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you should use the format `"%f"`.

---

With

```
int num = 5.0 + 2;
```

you convert the result of `5.0 + 2` into the `int` value `7`. Then you print the `int` value using the correct format specifier.

Comment: result of  `printf("%d\n", 1.1 );` is garbage value

result of  `printf("%d\n", 5.0 );` is 0 


What's the difference between the two?


Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @PWS - 0 is not less garbage. Undefined is undefined, period.

Comment: @PWS Not "garbage", just not what you expect it to be. As mentioned, mismatching format and argument type leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which theoretically could summon [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) or reformat your hard-drive.

Answer (score 6):

In all expressions, every operand has a type. `5.0` has type `double`. `2` has type `int`.

Whenever a double and an integer are used as operands of the same operator, the integer is silently converted to a double before calculation. The result is of type `double`.

And so you pass `double` to `printf`, but you have told it to expect an `int`, since you used `%d`. The result is a bug, the outcome is not defined.

But in case of `int num = 5.0 + 2;`, you first get a result as `double`, `7.0`. Then force a conversion back to `int`. That code is equivalent to:

```
int num = (int)((double)5.0 + (double)2);
```

More details here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 3):

The result of expression `5.0 + 2` is of type `double`, since at least one of the two operands of operator `+` here is a floating point / double value (so the other one will be converted to `double` before adding).

If you write `printf("%d\n", 5.0 + 2)`, you will pass a floating point value where the format specifier actually expects an `int`. This mismatch is undefined behaviour, and the `0` you receive could be something else (another number, a crash, a .... what ever), too.

`int num = 5.0 + 2`, in contrast, will convert the `double`-value resulting from `5.0 + 2` back to an integral value (discarding any fractional part). So the value of `num` will be `7` and will be - since `num` is an integral type - valid in conjunction with format specifier `%d` then.

Answer (score 1):

`5.0+2` is typed `double`.

The compiler warning for

```
int main() { return _Generic(5.0 + 2, struct foo: 0); }
```

should tell you as much if

```
int main() { return _Generic(5.0 + 2, double: 5.0+2); }
```

compiling without error doesn't.

Matching `"%d"` with a `double` in `printf` results in undefined behavior.

Any result is legal, including your harddrive getting erased (unlikely to happen unless your program already has such functionality somewhere in it; if it does, UB can well result it it being inadvertently invoked).

Answer (score 0):

The usual arithmetic conversions are implicitly performed to cast their values to a common type. The compiler first performs integer promotion; if the operands still have different types, then they are converted to the type that appears highest in the following hierarchy -

[image]

In `int num = 5.0 + 2;` this code snippet you are adding a float with integer and storing back to integer again. So, c automatically casts the result into integer to store in an integer type variable. So, while printing using %d, it prints fine.

But, in `printf("%d\n", 5.0 + 2);` this code snippet, the addition is casted into floating point number as float has higher priority over integer, but you are printing it using %d. Here mismatch of format specifier causing the unexpected result.